# Time limit exceeded with recursion, works on 90/91 test cases, fails on large input

Tags: python, recursion

LeetCode problem 20 - valid parentheses. Return true if input string is 'valid'.

1. Open brackets must be closed by the same type of brackets.
2. Open brackets must be closed in the correct order.

Code passes 90/91 test cases, but exceeds time limit on last case with input string of ~7000 characters. Function is recursive, so I tried importing sys to manually increase recursion limit - no success. Very curious about this error - thanks!

```
class Solution(object):
def isValid(self, s):
    import sys
    sys.setrecursionlimit(10**6) 

    #recursion base case
    def base(s):
        return True if len(s) == 0 else False
        
    open = ['(', '[', '{']
    close = [')', ']', '}']
    pairs = zip(open, close)
    
    #function to return true for open/close adjacent pair
    def isPartner(s):            
        return True if s[0] in open and s[1] in close and open.index(s[0]) == close.index(s[1]) else False
    
    if len(s) == 1:
        return False        
    
    if len(s) == 2:
        return isPartner(s)
    
    for i, j in enumerate(s):
        if all(j not in open for j in s) or all(j not in close for j in s):
            return False
        elif isPartner(j + s[i+1]):
            s1 = s.replace(j + s[i+1], '', 1)
            return True if base(s1) else self.isValid(s1)
        elif s[i+1] in open:
            continue
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: Why would you think that increasing the recursion limit would help? You didn't run into the limit, the problem is that your algorithm is too slow.

Comment: @Barmar because I found the default limit is 1000

Comment: What does that have to do with it? You got *time* limit exceeded, not *recursion* limit exceeded.

Comment: Please fix the indentation. Do you really have nested functions, or are they all at top-level in the class?

Comment: You don't need recursion for this. Use a stack to record the opening brackets. Whenever you get an opening bracket, push it onto the stack. When you get a closing bracket, pop the stack and check that they match.

Comment: Use a dictionary for partners: `{')': '(', ']': '[', '}': '{'}`

Comment: ok thank you guys - getting back into programming after a few years, so definitely still rusty. I appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your recursive algorithm is allocating lots of intermediate strings. A simpler algorithm is to just step through the string sequentially, checking that whenever you find a closing bracket it properly matches an opening bracket.

Use a list as a stack to hold all the opening brackets that haven't been closed yet. Whenever you get a closing bracket, you pop the last bracket off the stack and check that they match.

```
class Solution:

    def isValid(self, s):
        open_brackets = ['(', '[', '{']
        close_brackets = [')', ']', '}']
        partners = dict(zip(close_brackets, open_brackets))
        bracket_stack = []
        
        for c in s:
            if c in open_brackets:
                bracket_stack.append(c)
            elif c in close_brackets:
                if len(bracket_stack) == 0: # no previous opening bracket
                    return False
                prev = bracket_stack.pop()
                if prev != partners[c]: # non-matching brackets
                    return False

        return len(bracket_stack) == 0 # True if all opening brackets have been popped
```